# Export Unity solution to WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm using Unity 5.3.3f1 Personal and into my code I have to use the Unity Ping class ( http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ping.html ). The building and execution in internal Unity Player (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kHmN.jpg) runs properly. However when I try to export this solution to WebGL, I recieve the next error:

> "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Ping' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

This is the C# source code with the related Ping code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using LitJson;

 public class PingScript : MonoBehaviour
 {
     string Url = null, pingAddress = "192.168.0.180";

     float pingStartTime;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start()
     {        
         CheckServerIp();
         if (Url == null)
         {                        
             pingAddress = "192.168.1.210";
             CheckServerIp();
         }
         print(Url);
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if (Url != null)
         {
             //Do something
         }
     }

     void CheckServerIp()
     {
         bool internetPossiblyAvailable;
         switch (Application.internetReachability)
         {
             case NetworkReachability.ReachableViaLocalAreaNetwork:
                 internetPossiblyAvailable = true;
                 break;
             default:
                 internetPossiblyAvailable = false;
                 break;
         }
         if (!internetPossiblyAvailable)
         {
             Url = null;
         }
         Ping ping = new Ping(pingAddress);
         pingStartTime = Time.time;
         if (ping != null)
         {            
             if (ping.isDone)
             {                
                 if (ping.time >= 0)
                 {                    
                     Url = "http://" + pingAddress + ":3200/api/pumpvalues";
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: WebGL has a lot of limitations and strange bugs. You can write the same code in javascript and call it remotely from Unity. That's gonna work for sure. [Docs on writing browser plugins for Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)

Answer (score 4):

The **only** Network stuff supported in Unity **WebGL** are the [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)  and the [UnityWebRequest](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html) class. You can still write your own ping function with WWW that checks if the server is available by connecting to it and checking if connection was successful.